# How to print something when runtime error occurs somewhere in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling

What normally happens is when code faces Runtime error , it simply terminates with runtime flag , what i intend to do is print a custom message before termination & i wish to 'return 0' ,ie terminate code normally after printing custom message as if runtime never happened .

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by ["runtime error"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error)?

Comment: Wherever your code's currently "terminat[ing] with runtime flag", add `std::cerr << "terminating due to error\n"; exit(0);`.  You can also structure your `main` function a la `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try { ... } catch(...) { std::cerr << "terminating due to exception\n"; }`.  You may want to install signal handlers for other types of errors, having them `cerr`/`exit` similarly: google "signal handler sigaction C++" for example code.

Comment: @TonyD : I didn't understand what you said but this won't work if i don't know where/how RTE is occuring .

Comment: @BoBTFish : yeah i mean error triggered when we are dividing by 0 or so on ..

Comment: You don't know where and why you have an error, but you want to hide it. I'm a bit worried.

Answer (score 5):

There are different reasons, why a programm might terminate.

First: An uncaught Exception was thrown. If that is, what you are looking for, then follow the advice, Paul Evans has given. With C++11, you might want to call `get_terminate()`, and call the returned teminate handler at the end of your new teminate handler:

```
terminate_handler old_terminate_handler = nullptr;

void new_terminate_handler() {
    std::cerr << "terminate due to error" << std::endl;
    if( old_terminate_handler != nullptr ) {
        old_terminate_handler();
    } else {
        std::abort();
    }
}

int main(int, char**) {
    old_terminate_handler = get_terminate();
    set_terminate(new_terminate_handler);
}
```

Second: a signal was received, that would normaly terminate the program. Install a signal handler to catch it:

```
void sig_handler(int signal) {
    new_terminate_handler();
}

// ...
std::signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);
std::signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler);
std::signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
// ...
```

Third: The operating system might simply decide to kill the process. That is either done by a normal signal signal (e.g. SIGTERM), or by a signal, that can not be handled (e.g. SIGKILL) In the second case, you have no chance to notice that inside the programm. The first case is already covered.

Answer (score 3):

First define your custom terminate handler, something like:

```
void f() {
    std::cout << \\ your custom message
}
```

then you want to call:

```
std::terminate_handler set_terminate( std::terminate_handler f );
```

to set up your function `f` as the terminate handler.

Comment: Sounds like solution but apparently it isn't working :/
See http://ideone.com/onWd1Q

Comment: @ZooOoz , it is not an error. In your case you are running over array boundary and that is not a well-defined error condition, it is an UB, and you cannot do anything meaningfull with it. It is a termination of your program by OS. It is out of your program scope and it cannot do anything with it.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot : But for UB isn't SEGFAULT returned ? here RTE is being returned isnt?

Comment: @ZooOoz You have to call the `set_terminate` function (eg `set_terminate(f)`) . In your code on ideone you're declaring a function locally.

Comment: @ZooOoz *"But for UB isn't SEGFAULT returned?"* - it could crash or corrupt the program behaviours in any way at all, that's why it's called *Undefined* Behaviour.  Google it.  *"here RTE is being returned isnt?"* - what's "RTE"?  There's a C++ exception class in `<stdexcept>` called `std::runtime_error`, but that's not thrown by out-of-bounds access, nor for divide by 0 or many other errors.  If you want a language that does more to tell you about errors in your programming, start with e.g. Java, which does a lot more checking (and is slower).